# Uploading a file using multer in Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, multer

Can you please explain in detail what is happening in these lines of code?
Why we are storing a function in the object with a callback?

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({


destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
 
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Answer (score 0):

The multer library is going to call the `destination` function when it wants to know what directory you want to put the uploads into.  It will call the `filename` function when it wants to now what filename you want to give a particular upload.

The reason both of these are functions is so that you have the option of examining the incoming request to compute a directory or filename that is appropriate for that specific request.  For example, if you wanted to store all files uploaded by one particular user in a directory for that specific user, you might look at the `req.session` object to determine which user it is making the upload and then you would compute the appropriate directory for that user.

The `destination` option may be provided as a plain string instead of a function if the value is known and is constant for all requests.  For example, you could do this:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: '/tmp/my-uploads',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})
```

The reason that you can communicate the final result via a callback rather than just a plain return value is in case you need to do some asynchronous operation (like look something up in a database) in order to compute what the directory or filename should be.  Communicating the result back by calling their supplied `cb(...)` function allows you do asynchronous operations and communicate back the result asynchronously.